# Vector Space over a Field from Golan

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

I want to build confidence with the following type of questions, as follows;

**Q1**: Let $V = \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$ be the vector space of all continuous functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to itself, and let $W = \{f \in V : |f(x)| \leq 1, \forall |x| \leq 1\}$.

Is $W$ a subspace of $V$?

My conclusion, is that $W$ is not a subspace of $V$. Let $f, g \in W$ such that $|f(x)| \leq 1$ and $|g(x)|\leq 1$. Then, by the triangle inequality we have, $|(f +g)(x)| = |f(x) + g(x)| \leq |f(x)| + |g(x)| \leq 2$. Clearly, $|(f +g)(x)| \leq 2$, and is not closed under addition, that is $f+g \notin W$.

**Q2**: Let $V = \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$ be the vector space, and let $W$ be the set of all functions satisfying the condition that there exists $c \in \mathbb{R}$ (which depends on $f$ ) such that $|f(x)| \leq c|x|$ for all 
$ x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Is $W$ a subspace of $V$?

My answer for this subset $W$ is that it is a subspace of $V$.

$W \neq \varnothing$ since the zero-function satisfies this for all $c > 0$.

$f + g \in W$, since let $f,g \in W$ such that there exists $c,d \in \mathbb{R}$ satisfying $|f(x)| \leq c|x|$ and $|g(x)| \leq d|x|$.

Now, $|(f + g)(x)| = |f(x) + g(x)| \leq |f(x)| + |g(x)| \leq c|x| + d|x| = (c + d)|x|$.

Hence, there is $(c + d) \in \mathbb{R}$ satisfying $|(f + g)(x)| \leq (c + d)|x|$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Similarly, we can show that $W$ is closed under scalar multiplication.

Is my answer and reasoning correct for the above questions. Thank you in advance for the kind help!

Comment: Usually, $\Bbb R^{\Bbb R}$ denotes the space of *arbitrary* functions $\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$, and something like $C(\Bbb R)$ denotes the continuous such functions

Answer (score 1):

**Q1** You show that $|f(x)+g(x)|\le 2$, but that does not (yet) make it impossible that the stronger inequality $|f(x)+g(x)|\le 1$ holds. How about trying some specific $f$ and $g$ in $V$ and shoing that their specific sum is $\notin V$?

**Q2** is fine. (Just watch out for absolute values when explcitily writing down that part about scalar multiples)

Comment: Oh, okay, I see with **Q1** we can use any constant functions $f(x) = 1$ and $g(x) = \frac{1}{2}$ and their sum is clearly $\notin W$. Thanks!